# guzzlephp 401 unauthorized issue

Tags: curl, guzzle, guzzle6

I am trying a guzzle http post request by

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
return $result;
```

where headers is

```
$headers = [
            'Authorization: key=' . $api_access_key,
            'Content-Type: application/json',
        ];
```

and post fields are

```
$fields = [
            'registration_ids' => $registrationIds,
            'data'             => [
                'title'   => $title,
                'message' => $message,
                'type'    => $type,
            ],
        ];
```

which response ok and as expected but if I call this request by guzzlehttp client by

```
$URL='https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send';

$client  = new \GuzzleHttp\Client(['http_errors' => false]);

$response = $client->request('POST', $URL,['form_params'=>$fields],
                                 ['headers'=>[
                                  'Authorization' => 'key='.$api_access_key,
                                   'Content-Type' => 'application/json']]);

return $response->getBody()->getContents();
```

It response with 401 unauthorized. Where is my problem? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you are using Guzzle 6. `request()` method [has only 3 parameters](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/blob/master/src/ClientInterface.php#L54), so you should merge your two arrays.

Something like this:

```
$response = $client->request('POST', $URL, [
    'form_params' => $fields,
    'headers'=> [
        'Authorization' => 'key='.$api_access_key,
        'Content-Type' => 'application/json'
]]);
```